# Trouble installing Pomegranate

Tags: python, windows, pomegranate

I've tried pip installing Pomegranate a few times, and also downloaded and installed VisualStudio c++ Buildtools, version 14.0.25420.1 . Unfortunately I'm still having issues installing the package, as shown by the code below. Anyone have any advice to get this installed correctly? I'm running Python 3.6.3 and my pip is upgraded. I had to cut some of the output due to limits

```
    Collecting pomegranate
      Using cached pomegranate-0.13.3.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.0 in c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pomegranate) (1.13.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.9.0b4 in c:\users\bbcon\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pomegranate) (0.15.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.0 in c:\users\bbcon\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pomegranate) (2.4)
    Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in c:\users\bbcon\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pomegranate) (1.5.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\bbcon\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from pomegranate) (5.3.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=2.0->pomegranate) (4.4.2)
    Building wheels for collected packages: pomegranate
      Building wheel for pomegranate (setup.py) ... error
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\bbcon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0yg_eznd\\pomegranate\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bbcon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0yg_eznd\\pomegranate\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\bbcon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-og4n4rhh'
           cwd: C:\Users\bbcon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\
      Complete output (339 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.6
      creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\callbacks.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\io.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      creating build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate/distributions\NeuralNetworkWrapper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate/distributions
      copying pomegranate/distributions\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate/distributions
      running egg_info
      writing pomegranate.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pomegranate.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to pomegranate.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pomegranate.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'pomegranate.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      writing manifest file 'pomegranate.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying pomegranate\BayesClassifier.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\BayesClassifier.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\BayesianNetwork.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\BayesianNetwork.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\FactorGraph.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\FactorGraph.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\MarkovChain.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\MarkovChain.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\MarkovNetwork.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\MarkovNetwork.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\NaiveBayes.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\NaiveBayes.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\base.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\base.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\base.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\bayes.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\bayes.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\bayes.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\gmm.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\gmm.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\hmm.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\hmm.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\kmeans.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\kmeans.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\parallel.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\parallel.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\utils.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate
      copying pomegranate\distributions\BernoulliDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\BernoulliDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\BernoulliDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\BetaDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\BetaDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\BetaDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\ConditionalProbabilityTable.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\ConditionalProbabilityTable.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\ConditionalProbabilityTable.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\DirichletDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\DirichletDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\DirichletDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\DiscreteDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\DiscreteDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\DiscreteDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\ExponentialDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\ExponentialDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\ExponentialDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\GammaDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\GammaDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\GammaDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\IndependentComponentsDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions  copying pomegranate\distributions\IndependentComponentsDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\IndependentComponentsDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\JointProbabilityTable.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\JointProbabilityTable.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\JointProbabilityTable.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\KernelDensities.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\KernelDensities.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\KernelDensities.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\LogNormalDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\LogNormalDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\LogNormalDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\MultivariateGaussianDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\MultivariateGaussianDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\MultivariateGaussianDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\NormalDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\NormalDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\NormalDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\PoissonDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\PoissonDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\PoissonDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\UniformDistribution.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\UniformDistribution.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\UniformDistribution.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\distributions.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\distributions.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      copying pomegranate\distributions\distributions.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions
      running build_ext
      building 'pomegranate.base' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-3.6
      creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
        c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_KernelDensities build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/KernelDensities.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions\KernelDensities.cp36-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\KernelDensities.cp36-win32.lib
           Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\KernelDensities.cp36-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\KernelDensities.cp36-win32.exp
        Generating code
        Finished generating code
        building 'pomegranate.distributions.IndependentComponentsDistribution' extension
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpomegranate/distributions/IndependentComponentsDistribution.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/IndependentComponentsDistribution.obj
        IndependentComponentsDistribution.c
        c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_IndependentComponentsDistribution build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/IndependentComponentsDistribution.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions\IndependentComponentsDistribution.cp36-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\IndependentComponentsDistribution.cp36-win32.lib
           Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\IndependentComponentsDistribution.cp36-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\IndependentComponentsDistribution.cp36-win32.exp
        Generating code
        Finished generating code
        building 'pomegranate.distributions.MultivariateGaussianDistribution' extension
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpomegranate/distributions/MultivariateGaussianDistribution.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/MultivariateGaussianDistribution.obj
        MultivariateGaussianDistribution.c
        c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_MultivariateGaussianDistribution build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/MultivariateGaussianDistribution.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions\MultivariateGaussianDistribution.cp36-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\MultivariateGaussianDistribution.cp36-win32.lib
           Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\MultivariateGaussianDistribution.cp36-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\MultivariateGaussianDistribution.cp36-win32.exp    Generating code
        Finished generating code
        building 'pomegranate.distributions.DirichletDistribution' extension
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpomegranate/distributions/DirichletDistribution.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/DirichletDistribution.obj
        DirichletDistribution.c
        c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_DirichletDistribution build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/DirichletDistribution.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions\DirichletDistribution.cp36-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\DirichletDistribution.cp36-win32.lib
           Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\DirichletDistribution.cp36-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\DirichletDistribution.cp36-win32.exp
        Generating code
        Finished generating code
        building 'pomegranate.distributions.ConditionalProbabilityTable' extension
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpomegranate/distributions/ConditionalProbabilityTable.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/ConditionalProbabilityTable.obj
        ConditionalProbabilityTable.c
        c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_ConditionalProbabilityTable build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/ConditionalProbabilityTable.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions\ConditionalProbabilityTable.cp36-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\ConditionalProbabilityTable.cp36-win32.lib
           Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\ConditionalProbabilityTable.cp36-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\ConditionalProbabilityTable.cp36-win32.exp
        Generating code
        Finished generating code
        building 'pomegranate.distributions.JointProbabilityTable' extension
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpomegranate/distributions/JointProbabilityTable.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/JointProbabilityTable.obj
        JointProbabilityTable.c
        c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /nodefaultlib:libucrt.lib ucrt.lib /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_JointProbabilityTable build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/JointProbabilityTable.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\pomegranate\distributions\JointProbabilityTable.cp36-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\JointProbabilityTable.cp36-win32.lib
           Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\JointProbabilityTable.cp36-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions\JointProbabilityTable.cp36-win32.exp
        Generating code
        Finished generating code
        building 'pomegranate.distributions.NeuralNetworkWrapper' extension
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-0yg_eznd\pomegranate\.eggs\numpy-1.19.0-py3.6-win32.egg\numpy\core\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcpomegranate/distributions/NeuralNetworkWrapper.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\pomegranate/distributions/NeuralNetworkWrapper.obj
        NeuralNetworkWrapper.c
        c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'pomegranate/distributions/NeuralNetworkWrapper.c': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\bbcon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0yg_eznd\\pomegranate\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\bbcon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0yg_eznd\\pomegranate\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\bbcon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mfed9iu0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\bbcon\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Include\pomegranate' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 5):

I found that if you pre-install Cython, that it resolves the issue. So, do a pip install Cython first before Pomegranate